# Django Forms API in GAE SDK 1.7.4

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-forms

I have read [under SDK release notes 1.7.3](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.7.3_-_October_23,_2012) that GAE supports Django 1.4. I know that Django models can't be used in GAE as we have Google's own models. But what about [Django Form API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/), particularly [displaying a form using a template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template)? Can that be used in SDK 1.7.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course you can use the form API and display it in the template. But what you can't do with plain Django on GAE is build a modelform automatically from a db.Model or ndb.Model. You have to use plain forms, defining the fields and setting the data back to the model entity manually.

Answer (score -1):

While you can't use django model forms, GAE provides a forms library that provides similar functionality for db.Model based models.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms

I'm not sure if there's an equivalent for ndb.